# Converting double to string in .NET isn't as precise as C++?

Tags: c#, floating-point, double, ieee

The following C++ program expectedly outputs `0.300000000000000040000`:

```c
cout << setprecision(40) << (0.1 + 0.2) << endl;
```

However the following C# code:

```cs
System.Console.WriteLine("{0:F40}", 0.1+0.2);
```

... unexpetedly outputs `0.3000000000000000000000000000000000000000`, while it (expectedly) evaluates `0.1+0.2 == 0.3` as `False`.

Where is the '4' and how can I output it?

Comment: The difference you're seeing is the C++ compiler added 0.1+0.2, while the C# compiler optimized it to 0.3 (approximately).

Comment: @Gabe... now that's just impossible. Or more precisely: about as likely as MS writing an fractional number arithmetics engine, and using it when compiling code, to "optimize" precisely such instances of operations on literals and compile-time-determinable values.

Comment: More precisely, the C# compiler runs on an x86 CPU so it does its internal calculations in 80-bit extended precision. That means it hard-codes the constant as 0.29999999999999999 instead of 0.30000000000000004.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you get if you say

```
System.Console.WriteLine("{0:R}", 0.1+0.2);
```

A [format string](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx) like `"F40"` will only add zeros to the end of the string. It will not give you extra precision compared to just `"G"`. On the other hand, `"R"`, will reveal two extra digits (or one if the last of the two digits extra is `0`) if (and only if) this is necessary to distinguish the number from a number closer to the string from `"G"`.

**Addition:** To get a better understanding of how the format strings work in .NET, try running the following code:

```
double a = BitConverter.ToDouble(new byte[] { 49, 51, 51, 51, 51, 51, 211, 63, }, 0);
double b = BitConverter.ToDouble(new byte[] { 50, 51, 51, 51, 51, 51, 211, 63, }, 0);
double c = BitConverter.ToDouble(new byte[] { 51, 51, 51, 51, 51, 51, 211, 63, }, 0);
double d = BitConverter.ToDouble(new byte[] { 52, 51, 51, 51, 51, 51, 211, 63, }, 0);
double e = BitConverter.ToDouble(new byte[] { 53, 51, 51, 51, 51, 51, 211, 63, }, 0);

Console.WriteLine("using G:");
Console.WriteLine(a.ToString());
Console.WriteLine(b.ToString());
Console.WriteLine(c.ToString());
Console.WriteLine(d.ToString());
Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
Console.WriteLine("using F40:");
Console.WriteLine(a.ToString("F40"));
Console.WriteLine(b.ToString("F40"));
Console.WriteLine(c.ToString("F40"));
Console.WriteLine(d.ToString("F40"));
Console.WriteLine(e.ToString("F40"));
Console.WriteLine("using R:");
Console.WriteLine(a.ToString("R"));
Console.WriteLine(b.ToString("R"));
Console.WriteLine(c.ToString("R"));
Console.WriteLine(d.ToString("R"));
Console.WriteLine(e.ToString("R"));
```

Here, `a`, `b`, `c`, `d`, and `e` are "neighbors" as `System.Double`s which is evident from the byte arrays. You should see that the `"R"` format string gives extra digits only in case of `a`, `b`, and `d`, `e`. For `c`, no extra digits are needed, but it is clear that **if** one were to write `c` with 17 figures, the last two of the 17 wouldn't be `00` (see also Jon Skeet's answer for the full decimal expansions which the methods built into .NET won't give you easily).

Answer (score 6):

It's not clear whether you'd want *exactly* the 4 followed by zeroes, but I have [some code](http://pobox.com/~skeet/csharp/DoubleConverter.cs) which will allow you to print out the exact decimal value of any `double`.

So as a test app:

```
using System;

class Test
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        double d1 = 0.1;        
        double d2 = 0.2;
        Console.WriteLine(DoubleConverter.ToExactString(d1 + d2));
        Console.WriteLine(DoubleConverter.ToExactString(0.3));
    }
}
```

Results:

```
0.3000000000000000444089209850062616169452667236328125
0.299999999999999988897769753748434595763683319091796875
```

I suspect that the built-in .NET formatters refuse to give you the "4" on the grounds that at that point the digits can't be "trusted" so to speak. They're just noise related to which value happens to be closest to the value you were really aiming for.

From the docs for [`System.Double`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.double.aspx):

> By default, a Double value contains 15 decimal digits of precision, although a maximum of 17 digits is maintained internally.

Comment: Thanks. I don't want the 4 followed by zeroes, but now the question is, where are the extra digits in the C++ code? :)

And also, C# can't do this without extra code (and lots of it, as i see)?!

Comment: @BorislavStanimirov: No idea about the C++ side. I don't know whether there's any simpler way of getting at the exact value in C# - I wrote that code ages ago; it's possible I could improve it now.

Comment: Apparently it's a question of fpu bit precision. Your code uses a "reimplementation" of the IEEE floating point standard while {0:R} gives the value that's stored internally and is the smallest possible, that will evaluate a==b as true.

Comment: @BorislavStanimirov: Yes, R will give the round-trip format. It's not the exact value that's stored internally though.

Comment: @BorislavStanimirov But if your purpose is to see if `0.3` and `d1 + d2` are the same or not, **from string representations**, using the format `"R"` will be helpful (showing enough extra digits to make you sure if the answer is yes or no), while `"F40"` which the Original Poster proposed is not helpful in this respect. If you want the exact and full decimal expansion, it's not built into .NET, but Jon Skeets code works fine for that.